# From what IP and fingerprint do Reddit bots deployed on Heroku (or equivalent) work?

Tags: heroku, automation, bots, reddit

I'm planning on using bots to moderate my Reddit servers. I own a bunch of them, and some of them have grown pretty rapidly and unexpectedly in a short period of time, so I think it's time I start automating parts of the moderation.

One of the options I'm considering is deploying a python script on Heroku or Dokku, and just leave that runnning.

What I would like to know is what exact location/IP address will reddit see the bot user logged in as. I will be having 5-10 bots, and I want to make sure I am not breaking any rules.

A long time ago I experimented with using selenium bots on Reddit, however Reddit has very strict policy with selenium bots, and all the accounts either got banned or shadowbanned.

I was doing somewhat spammy things with my selenium bots, however I plan on using these bots strictly for moderation purposes, and I'd like to know what precautions I'd need to take to avoid bans/shadowbans.

Also, do I need to use a different Heroku location for each bot? I remember using a multi-fingerprint browser with different proxies for my selenium bots.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "fingerprint", but [the IP address range is pretty broad](https://help.heroku.com/JS13Y78I/i-need-to-add-heroku-dynos-to-our-allowlist-what-are-ip-address-ranges-in-use-at-heroku). Bots are permitted on Reddit, so as long as you follow [the rules](https://www.reddit.com/wiki/bottiquette/) I can't see any reason you'd get banned. But that's super off-topic here.

Comment: I'm referring to browser fingerprint. I'm assuming reddit bots on heroku don't have any browser fingerprint since they communicate directly with the API.